# Google maps android V2: how to pan map to show InfoWindow

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a map with custom Infowindow and I'd like to make sure that every time a user clicks a marker the info window will be fully visible, how can i do that?

I already have some code to prevent centering on clicked marker but i have no idea how to do what i need:

```
private void preventMarkerCenter(){
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // Check if there is an open info window
            if (lastOpenned != null) {
                // Close the info window
                lastOpenned.hideInfoWindow();

                // Is the marker the same marker that was already open
                if (lastOpenned.equals(marker)) {
                    // Nullify the lastOpenned object
                    lastOpenned = null;
                    // Return so that the info window isn't openned again
                    return true;
                } 
            }

            // Open the info window for the marker
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            // Re-assign the last openned such that we can close it later
            lastOpenned = marker;

            // Event was handled by our code do not launch default behaviour.
            return true;
        }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html

The "default behavior" that you are blocking by returning `true` is to show the info window, and then center the map on the marker.

I think if you don't call `marker.showInfoWindow()`, and return `false` you'll get what you want.

If what you want is to pan the map just enough to show the info window, then you have to do those calculations yourself and pan the map with a `CameraUpdateFactory`.`CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy()` or something like that.

Comment: yeah, figured that much, the problem is how to make the calculations? how do i measure the size and location of the info window?